# CURL return null on json load file

Tags: php, json, curl

My code below return **NULL** when I try to load a json file with Curl in PHP ! What I did wrong ? I check my phpinfo and curl is enabled.

```
    // set HTTP header
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/json.json';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // DUMP
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

My json file :

```
{
    "0": {
        "temps": "09:03:09",
        "temps_bonus": "-00:16:00",
        "ordre": 1,
        "numero": "10",
        "ecart": ""
    },
    "1": {
        "temps": "09:15:19",
        "temps_bonus": "-00:17:00",
        "ordre": 2,
        "numero": "7",
        "ecart": "00:12:10"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: `$result`'s value is `false` or that json? Got some php errors?

Comment: No php errors ! Dump return NULL on the screen.

Comment: That is the result of `json_decode`, that tells us nothing about the problem. What is `$result`?

Comment: Oh OK ! With echo $result; I get :
You don't have permission to access json.json on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But with $result = file_get_contents(json.json); I have to problem after :
$jsonValid = json_decode($result, true);

Comment: Do I need to pass my login and password in CURL ?

Comment: See what 403 code is about.

Comment: I add CURLOPT_USERAGENT and it works fine now ! Thanks for your help @Leggendario ;))